# Create a record for a model other than the current routes model

Tags: ember.js, model, ember-data

I have an `items` route that lists items, when I click one I go to an `item` route that shows the one item. Pretty standard and I've set it up such that Ember magic is taking care of the dynamic part of the `item` route.

In the `item` route I have an action handler that I want to create a bid on that item, items have many bids and bids belong to one item and one user.

In my `item` route I've tried just calling

```
  var newBid = this.store.createRecord('bid', {
          user_id: 29,
          item_id: 2565,
          bid_amt: 600
        });
  newBid.save().then(function(bid){
    console.log('saved bid\n');
    console.log(bid);
  }).catch(function(reason){
    console.log(reason)
  });
```

But in the console I'm getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: DS.default.Attr is not a function
```

Is there a way to do this with ember-data without having to switch to a straight Ajax call?

EDIT:

My adapter looks like this

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api'
});
```

The item model looks like this

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  canceled: DS.attr('boolean'),
  bid: DS.hasMany('bid')
});
```

User model looks like this

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    bid: DS.hasMany('bid')
});
```

And the bid model looks like this

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  item: DS.belongsTo('item')
});
```

I took out all the other attributes on the models as the models are quite large and I don't think they matter, there are no defaults being set for any of them.

Comment: can you share your models and what adapter you're using?

Answer (score 1):

In ember Data you'll always have to pass the whole model, but not only the id, to a related item.
So in your case you'd have to do something like:

```
let user = this.store.peekRecord('user',29);
let item = this.store.peekRecord('item', 2565);

var newBid = this.store.createRecord('bid', {
      user: user,
      item: item,
      bid_amt: 600
    });
```

Note, that if the requested records are not yet in your store, but need to be fetched from the server you'd have to call `findrecords` instead of `peekRecords` and you'll receive a promise only. In that case you'll have to wait for the promises to resolve before creating the new record!!!